# SQL query sample

Tags: sql

my table is look like this order.. I would like count the TermID's with these conditions; If it's possible also want to get resultset with these headers 
- TermID must have close or open status
- TermID Status must turn to Open (close to open)
- Status Date (open status) must be bigger date than close status date

with my regards,

```
ID        TermID Status Date
103990107 103641 Close 28/05/2010
104000600 103641 Open 31/05/2010
103980976 106458 Close 26/05/2010
103990045 106458 Open 27/05/2010
103939537 106475 Open 18/05/2010
103908130 117220 Open 13/05/2010
103929653 117220 Open 13/05/2010
103999017 117360 Open 31/05/2010
103834814 117402 Open 05/05/2010
103993973 117420 Open 28/05/2010
103849795 119377 Close 05/05/2010
103955266 119377 Close 21/05/2010
103995229 119377 Close 29/05/2010
103979873 119704 Open 25/05/2010
103832225 119767 Open 04/05/2010
103925429 123229 Close 15/05/2010
103986986 123932 Open 27/05/2010
```

Comment: How do you know what date is the newest in `117220`, and `119377` they're all marked with the same date, and status?

Comment: You may want to try restating your question. You're asking to count TermIDs, yet you also want to change TermID Statuses and Dates?  As the above is written, I'm not sure what you want to do.  I'd break the question down into individual pieces, instead of trying to state your entire problem at once.

Comment: 117220 and 119377, these termIDs will be ommitted because they do not have open and close status

Comment: I think my question is like grouping by termIDs and filtering them whose status is open now (before it was "close"-d") Now and before meanings is get by "date" field

Comment: In other words, the resultset will contain termID '106458' because it was first closed on 26/05/2010 and then opened on 27/05/2010. A record for a termID where status = 'Open' is placed into the table after a record for a termID with status = 'Close'. You want to get the termIDs that were previously 'Close'. --- I was getting confused by your English; close is a present tense verb; closed is a perfect, meaning the action is done in the past. When you said 'open' and 'close' in your question, I thought you were looking for actions to occur.  Instead they are state labels.  Makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking two questions here:

---

**1.**  How do I count all TermIDs?

**Answer:**  You use the `count(...)` aggregate function in SQL.

Example:

```
SELECT count(TermID) from <table>
```

This will count all TermIDs in your table.

---

**2.**  How do I update my records to have a new status / status date?

**Answer:**  Use the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE <table>
SET Status = 'Open', <column name> = <value>, ...
WHERE Staus = 'Closed'
```

Note:  You're question seems vague, so the above may not work well.  Please tailor to your specific use cases.

Comment: ie, as a result one of the termID is going to be '106458' because it is firstly close on 26/05/2010 and then open on 27/05/2010. Open status occurs after close status.
I would like to get termIDs that was closed and now it is open

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It will work in oracle

```
SELECT TermID, COUNT(*) CNT FROM
 (
 SELECT ID,TermID,Status, Date,
 LEAD(Status,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY TermID ORDER BY Date DESC) NEXT_STATUS,
 FROM MYTABLE
 ) 
WHERE Status = 'Close' AND NEXT_STATUS = 'Open';
```

Comment: how could you write this query in tsql syntax

Comment: This should work in T-SQL if it supports the windowing functions in SQL:2003.  You should be able to verify that by your documentation.